# Gain or loss of tickets in a raffle?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I've got a probability question, and I feel like I might be missing a step in my process. It says:

A company offers a raffle whose grand prize is a 60,000 dollar new car.  Additional prizes are a 1,000 dollar television and a 500 dollar computer.  Tickets cost 20 dollars each. Ticket income will be donated to a charity. If 3,000 tickets are sold, what is the expected gain or loss (in dollars) of each ticket? (Round your answer to the nearest cent.)

Since each prize has a 1/3000 probability, I figured I would just multiply that number by each of the prizes (60000, 1000, and 500), add those up and then compare to the 20 dollar ticket cost. This would leave me with 20 + 0.33333 + 0.166667, which is about 20.50 when rounded to the nearest cent. That means that the gain for each ticket would be 50 cents, correct? Am I doing this right? Thanks!

Comment: The expected gain is indeed 50 cents for each ticket.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I was wondering if I needed to subtract the 20 dollars from the 60000, 1000, and 500 prize amounts before multiplying by 1/3000, but I guess not?

Comment: The cost of 20 dollars are sure. So multiplying it by 1/3000 is false.